# Data Adapter not able to update records added/updated/deleted in .NET

Tags: datagridview, crud, nsoperation

Steps,

1. Crate window application with single form
2. add new datasource from Data->Add new Data source
3. Goto Data->Show Data Source
4. Drop any table to form. This step will add tow controls. a. DataGridView b. Binding Navigator

press F5 to run.

I am able to view all the records but not able to do add/update/delete.

Below is the code of the form that is generated by VS.

```
namespace TestingGrid
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.testBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.testTableAdapter.Update( this.testDataSet.Test );

        }

        private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testDataSet.Test' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.testTableAdapter.Fill( this.testDataSet.Test );

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey did you not get a answer yet?

You need to add a primary key to your sql table. 
without the primary key the data adapter will not be able to delete or edit any records.

i just used a Id integer that auto increments; so i do not need to show the id in my datagrid view.